# Where is the included PHP interpreter in the GAE SDK?

Tags: php, macos, google-app-engine

Google App Engine [version 1.8.5](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) clearly says that "the Mac OSX SDK now includes a PHP interpreter, installing PHP separately is no longer required."  However, I don't seem to find it.  I know I could just install php-cgi on my own, but if it were indeed included in the SDK, I wouldn't want to install another copy.

Comment: always been like that, I always use the terminal to exe php applications

Comment: What do you get with `which php` at the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is here: /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi